# Rewriting multiple link URLs in a string

Tags: php, preg-replace, replace

I have a long string that contains multiple HTML links that looks like this:

```
<a href="example.com">My Link></a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://example2.com">A different Link</a>
```

etc.

I need to rewrite these links in PHP so that they send the traffic thru my redirector, so I can tell users they are now leaving to an external domain, etc.  My redirector is located at mydomain.com/leaving.php.  What I want to do is rewrite these links to something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.mydomain.com/leaving.php/[URL ENCODED LINK FROM ABOVE]">My Link>
```

Since not all urls have http:// to begin with I think I need to first strip those from all href links.

How can I grep the correct HTML links (ignoring image src) and url_encode them, and place them back in the original string.

EDIT: Just to clearify, I am not looking for help with the redirection part, just how to replace several URLs within a large string when they sometimes have http

Comment: Is the malformed anchor tag in the first code example by desire or a mistake?

Comment: Good eye, that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a pseudo that you can modify it as you need.

You need first a .htaccess file that contents following lines;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^leaving/(.*)$ leaving.php?url=$1 [L]
```

And in `leaving.php`;

```
$url = trim(urldecode($_GET['url']));
// check url is exists
if ($url == '') {
    header('Location: http://www.mydomain.com/');
    exit;
}
// add http if needs
if (substr($url, 0, 7) != 'http://') {
    $url = 'http://'. $url;
}

// send it to target
header('Location: '. $url);
exit;
```

UPDATE:

If you trying this on server-side, it's useless, cos if PHP sent output once, then u cannot use `preg's` anymore. So, if want to do this on client-side, following code or somthing like will help you.

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
    link, href, i = 0;
while (link = links[i++]) {
    // get real url applying getAttribute with "2" params
    if ((href = link.getAttribute("href", 2)) !== null
            // skip non-href links
            && href.charAt(0) !== "#") {
        // add http if not exists
        if (href.substring(0, 7) !== 'http://') {
            href = "http://"+ href
        }
        link.href = "http://www.mydomain.com/leaving/"+ href;
    }
}
```

Comment: edited to clearify -- I need to figure out how to grab multiple urls within a string and replace them (with my redirecting link) not help with the redirector itself

Comment: So, where to try to this exactly? Server-side: (why, if php send output once then you can't use preg's anymore)? Client-side: u need use js instead php for this, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Editing XML using regular expressions is error-prone and awkward, but there are handy tools around.

Easiest end most reliable way to edit HTML is using DOM and XPath. Find all links and rewrite them.

Possibly you want to add some filter to exclude internal URLs. You can either do this in the XPath query (possibly more elegant and faster as less results have to be processed) or the `foreach` loop.

```
<?php
    $html = <<< HTML
<p>
<a href="example.com">My Link>
<a href="http://example2.com">A different Link</a>
</p>
HTML;

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    // Find all anchor elements containing a href attribute
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $anchors = $xpath->query('//a[@href]');

    // Replace all href attributes with redirection url
    foreach ($anchors as $anchor)
        // Possibly filter internal URLs?
        $anchor->setAttribute('href', 'http://www.mydomain.com/leaving.php/'.urlencode($anchor->getAttribute('href')));

    // Save html with replaced links
    $newHtml = $dom->saveXml($dom->documentElement);
?>
```